# Joomla session variables and retrieving wrong values

Tags: php, session, joomla

I'm doing some custom coding for a Joomla installation that uses jReviews.
In a module on my home page I pass an array of content id's to a session variable (step 1) and then in other pages such as Top Products or Special Offers I might send a different set of values to the same session variable (step 2), each time the values are related to certain attributes, something like a 'related products' function. When finally I view a product, I should get the values sent in step 2 but instead, I'm getting the values from step 1.

This is what I'm doing:

Step 1:

```
$db =& JFactory::getDBO();
$query = "select * from jos_jreviews_content jrc 
join jos_content jc on jrc.contentid = jc.id 
where jc.state=1 and jc.catid=10 order by jc.id desc limit 100";
//state 1= published, catid 10= products, 
$db->setQuery($query);
$allproducts = $db->loadObjectList(); 
$nav_session = JFactory::getSession();
$nav_listings_ids = array();

if(count($allproducts)) {
    $i=0;

    foreach($allproducts as $relatedproduct) {
        $listingid = $relatedproduct->id;
        $alias = $relatedproduct->alias;
        $nav_listings_ids[$i]["id"] = $relatedproduct->contentid;
        $nav_listings_ids[$i]["link"] = "index.php?option=com_content&view=article&catid=10:products&id=".$listingid.":".$alias."&Itemid=16";
        $nav_listings_ids[$i]["title"] = $relatedproduct->title;
        $i++;
    }
}

// Save to session var 
$nav_session->set('related_results_listings', $nav_listings_ids);
```

Step 2:

```
$jrcompanyname = '*'.$listing['Field']['pairs']['jr_companyname']['value'][0].'*';

$db =& JFactory::getDBO();
$query = "select * from jos_jreviews_content jrc 
join jos_content jc on jrc.contentid = jc.id 
where jrc.jr_companyname = '".$jrcompanyname."' and jc.state=1 and jc.catid=10 order by jrc.contentid desc";
$db->setQuery($query);
$relatedproducts = $db->loadObjectList(); 

$nav_session = JFactory::getSession();

$nav_listings_ids = array();

if(count($relatedproducts)) {
    $i=0;

    foreach($relatedproducts as $relatedproduct) { 
        $listingid = $relatedproduct->id;
        $alias = $relatedproduct->alias;
        $nav_listings_ids[$i]["id"] = $relatedproduct->contentid;
        $nav_listings_ids[$i]["link"] = "index.php?option=com_content&view=article&catid=10:products&id=".$listingid.":".$alias."&Itemid=16";
        $nav_listings_ids[$i]["title"] = $relatedproduct->title;
        $i++;
    }
}

// Save session
$nav_session->set('related_results_listings', $nav_listings_ids);
```

On my product page I loop through the values of $_SESSION['related_results_listings'] to find the position of the item I'm viewing:

```
$nav_session = JFactory::getSession();

$nav_listings = $nav_session->get("related_results_listings");

// Locate the current listing in the search results list and retrieve the previous and next items

$index = 0;
for( $i=0; $i<count($nav_listings); $i++ )
{
    if( $nav_listings[$i]["id"] == $listing['Listing']['listing_id'] )
    {
        $index = $i;
        break;
    }   
}
```

I'll be glad to explain any of the above if someone is willing to help me out. Thanks in advance and Happy New Year to all!